# delete_others_posts capability as false not working

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, roles, capability

I am trying to define new user role based on custom post type capabilities. Apart from other capabilities I want this role just to delete its own posts and not other users posts.

To accomplish this I defined `delete_others_posts(delete_others_dictionary_entry)` as `false` but somehow it's not working and every user with this new role are able to delete every other users posts.

```
add_action('init', 'setup_dictionary_post');

//Register custom post type    
function setup_dictionary_post() {

    $capabilities = array(
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_dictionary_entry',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_dictionary_entry',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_dictionary_entry',
            'delete_posts' => 'delete_dictionary_entry',
            'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_dictionary_entry',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_dictionary_entry'
    );

    $labels = array(
            'name' => 'Dictionary Entries',
              'singular_name' => 'Dictionary Entry',
              'menu_name' => 'Dictionary Entries',
              'add_new' => 'Add New',
              'add_new_item' => 'Add New Dictionary Entry',
              'edit' => 'Edit entry',
              'edit_item' => 'Edit Dictionary Entry',
              'new_item' => 'New Dictionary Entry',
              'view' => 'View Dictionary Entry',
              'view_item' => 'View Dictionary Entry',
              'search_items' => 'Search Dictionary Entries',
              'not_found' => 'No Dictionary Entries Found',
              'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Dictionary Entries Found in Trash',
              'parent' => 'Parent Dictionary Entry');

            register_post_type('dictionary_entry', 
                array(
                    'label' => 'Dictionary Entries',
                    'description' => '',
                    'public' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'show_in_menu' => true,
                    'capability_type' => 'dictionary_entry',
                    'capabilities'=>$capabilities,
                    'hierarchical' => false,
                    'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'supports' => array('title','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),
                    'labels' => $labels,
                    )
            );

            flush_rewrite_rules(false);

            /********************** CUSTOM ROLE *****************************/
            remove_role('dictionary_entry_author');
            add_role('dictionary_entry_author', 
              'Dictionary Helper', array(
                    'publish_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'edit_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'edit_others_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'delete_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'delete_others_dictionary_entry' => false,
                    'read_private_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'read_dictionary_entry' => true,
                    'read' => true
            ));
}
```

Comment: This is not gonna answer your question but you should never `flush_rewrite_rules` on every init, as it is expensive. Check the first point under __Important__ on https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: thank you. I was actually thinking to use it on plugin activation hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map your capabilites to actual capabilities first. 
Something along the lines of:

```
add_filter('map_meta_cap', function($caps, $cap, $user_id, $args) {
    $cap_type = 'dictionary_entry';

    /* If editing, deleting, or reading a cpt, get the post and post type object. */
    if ( 'edit_' . $cap_type == $cap || 'delete_' . $cap_type == $cap || 'read_' . $cap_type == $cap ) {
        $post = \get_post($args[0]);
        $post_type = \get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

        /* Set an empty array for the caps. */
        $caps = array();
    }

    /* If editing a cpt, assign the required capability. */
    if ( 'edit_' . $cap_type == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->edit_others_posts;
    }

    /* If deleting a cpt, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'delete_' . $cap_type == $cap ) {
        if ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_posts;
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->delete_others_posts;
    }

    /* If reading a private cpt, assign the required capability. */
    elseif ( 'read_' . $cap_type == $cap ) {

        if ( 'private' != $post->post_status )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        elseif ( $user_id == $post->post_author )
            $caps[] = 'read';
        else
            $caps[] = $post_type->cap->read_private_posts;
    }

    /* Return the capabilities required by the user. */
    return $caps;
}, 10, 4);
```

Also check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/map_meta_cap (although this is rather thin) and http://mannieschumpert.com/blog/wordpress-capabilities-magic-with-map_meta_cap/